# Implementing own iterator for AMF functions

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I want to implement an iterator, to iterate over an anti monotonic intervals, such interval contains anti monotonic functions. So the iterator must iterate over the interval and return anti monotonic functions. The functions must be dynamically calculated from the top or the bottom element.

```
class AMFInterval {
    public:
        class AMFIterator : public iterator<forward_iterator_tag, AMFunction> {
            friend class AMFunction;
            public:
                AMFunction* amf;
                AMFIterator(AMFInterval interval) {amf = &interval.from;};
                const reference operator*() {return *amf;}

        };

    private:
        AMFunction from;
        AMFunction till;
        typedef AMFIterator iterator;
    public:
        AMFInterval(AMFunction bottom, AMFunction top);
        virtual ~AMFInterval();

        //iterator
        iterator begin() {return iterator(*this);};
        iterator end() {return iterator(*this);};


        // query
        string toString();

        // class
        static AMFInterval fullspace(int n);
    };
```

I also add the code for the parser:

```
AMFunction Parser::parse_amf(string a) {
    int size = a.size();
    AMFunction amf;
    bool sbs = false;
    SmallBasicSet s;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        if (sbs && a[i] != ']' && a[i] != ',' && a[i] != ' ') {
            s.quickadd(a[i] - '0');
        } else if ( a[i] == '[' ) {
            sbs = true;
            s = SmallBasicSet();
        } else if ( a[i] == ']' ) {
            sbs = false;
            amf.addSet(s);
        }
    }
    return amf;
}
```

If we test the iterator we got "**EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)**", it can't return the sting b, but if i debug, the correct value is in the pointer, here is the test:

```
void test_iterator() {
    Parser p;
    AMFInterval amf(p.parse_amf("{[1]}"), p.parse_amf("{}"));
    AMFInterval::AMFIterator freddy = amf.begin();
    //cout << p.parse_amf("{[1,2,3]}").toString() << endl;
    AMFunction &b = *(freddy.amf);
    cout <<  b.toString();
    //cout << (*amf.end()).toString() << endl;

}
```

Comment: I might need to see the Parser and the AMFInterval constructor to see what's going on. And copy consructor for AMFunction

Comment: Note that `AMFIterator(AMFInterval interval) {amf = &interval.from;};`
is taking a copy of the AMFInterval and using its address.

Comment: Color me dense, but how to you distinguish `begin()` and `end()` when they both return the same iterator?